# Date comparison with the last second of a day

Tags: sql, code-smell, comparison

Would you consider

```
WHERE SomeDate <= '2018-01-01 23:59:59'
```

instead of

```
WHERE SomeDate < '2018-01-02'
```

When the intention is that SomeDate goes no further then 2018-01-01

a code smell and if yes then why

Comment: This is not a question of style, it's a difference in semantics. The two tests either do the same or they don't, depending on how high the resolution of your `Date` data type is.

Comment: Added a clarification about the intention

Comment: Yes, just arguing with a collegue, my argument is that it is an unnecessary complication and a potential bug (though highly unlikely). His argument is that the first one is more obvious than the second one and that relaistically the bug won't hapen.

Comment: Have you (and your colleague) considered the existence of [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second)? '2016-12-31 23:59:60' is a Date value that actually happened and it is part of the day '2016-31-12'.

Comment: Anecdotal: I find these are often paired with (or at least, the practice derived from) using a greater-than comparison for 'safety' against the underlying type. For example, if you wanted "3rd Jan or later", then `SomeDate > '2018-01-02'` works when `SomeDate` is a `date`, but can fail when `SomeDate` is a `datetime`, because `2018-01-02` is `2018-01-02 00:00:00`, and so something like `2018-01-02 15:30` satisfies the condition. Of course, there's much better ways to do that (`SomeDate >= '2018-01-03'`), but I've found that to be the reason why `23:59:59`s crop up in SQL sometimes.

Answer (score 4):

I would *always* use

```
SomeDate < '2018-01-02'
```

1. Do you really want to worry about the resolution of the underlying datatype when you make the selection?
2. It's neater
3. It works with spans of time.  2018-01-01 + 1 day = 2018-01-02
4. = 2018-01-01 23:59:59 happens 1 second earlier than < 2018-01-02
5. Leap seconds are a thing so you need <= 2016-12-31 23:59:60

I will add more reasons as I think of them. There are many.

Comment: How about leap seconds?  Now it's `<= ... 23:59:60`

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the resolution of your data type.

If all you can represent is seconds, then the two are equivalent, and there's no point in writing the more complicated expression. It's a smell because it gives the impression that whoever wrote this doesn't know how their date type works.

If you can represent milliseconds or even microseconds, then the first test is stricter than the second, so they are not interchangeable. Since it is much more likely that you want to compare against "midnight" rather than "less than 1s before midnight", in this case the first alternative is probably outright wrong.

Hence, the second alternative is probably preferable in most circumstances. If you really do have to check against a time immediately before midnight (perhaps you're creating a bomb timer in a superhero movie?), this is sufficiently unusual that you should add a comment explaining that yes, you actually do have to compare against this weird value.

Answer (score 2):

The most reliable way is to always use **'>='** when you need to define the beginning of a period, and **'<'** when you need to define the end of a period:

```
WHERE SomeDate >= '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND SomeDate < '2019-02-01 00:00:00'
```

This approach allows to minimize the number of possible *"surprises"*.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn’t say it is a code smell, I would say neither of your options say exactly what you mean.  I would write that as:

```
WHERE cast(somedatetime as Date) <= '2018-01-01'
```

This says exactly what you want it to: when the date part of somedatetime, considered as a date, is less than or equal to this other date, include it in the results.

If somedatetime is supposed to just hold dates then change it to somedate and remove the cast.

I use the less-than-equal-to approach because it is clear that the final date is intentional.